# ssis reset variable before reusing

Tags: sql-server, variables, ssis, etl, sql-server-data-tools

I have a variable `@[User::fileExist]` within my ssis package which I use to return a result if a file exists.

It is defaulted to `0` then if a file exists it will return `1`. I decided to re use this variable later on in the package how do I reset this variable before using it again

Comment: There are several ways. One is to reset your variable inside a script component / script task. - Should it be done under Control Flow or Data Flow? And do you want to reset it back to 0 ?

Comment: And how come you want to reset? Cant you just overwrite the value? And if something doesnt exists you hardcode it to 0?

Comment: @plaidDK my variable is fileExist and have set value to 0. I have a script task that checks a file location if file exists then this variable is set to 1 and it goes down a different path within package. the issue is I check for another file after this and use the same variable but it is already defaulted to 1 from bein run previously so I want to reset to 0 before re using

Comment: Then just set it to 0 before you use it again in top of script task in the new path or make a new script task in the new path which sets it to 0

Comment: You can achieve this using Script task or if your SQL server version is newer than 2008 you can use expression task. I think that you have good answers. Did you try them?

Comment: @sql2015 why ignoring others on this question, you have answers and comments that you didn't make any reply on them ??!!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## Using Expression Task

*SQL Server 2012 or newer*

You can use an expression task to achieve this. just add an expression task to your package and use the following expression

```
@[User::fileExist] = 0
```

*Read more @:*

- [Expression Task](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/control-flow/expression-task)
- [Use an Expression in a Data Flow Component](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/9181b998-d24a-41fb-bb3c-14eee34f910d)

---

## Using Script Task

Or you can use a script task to achieve this, just add a script task to your package, choose this variable as a `ReadWrite Variable` and inside the script write the following code *(you have to select Microsoft Visual Basic as script Language)*:

```
Public Sub Main()
    Dts.Variables.Item("fileExist").Value = 0

    Dts.TaskResult = ScriptResults.Success

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

You can reset the value of the variable with a Script task.

Comment: I agree with you. But when you answer, cant you provide an example it will make your answer a bit better :)

Comment: I give examples when I feel they might be needed, but in this case, I felt a nudge in the right direction would probably be enough.

Answer (score 0):

How about skipping the reset and just setting it:

```
Dts.Variables["fileExists"].Value = System.IO.File.Exists(filePath);
```

Comment: if fileExists is data type int then change to System.IO.File.Exists(filePath)?1:0

Answer (score 0):

One of the standard and more transparent approaches would be creating sequence container where you want your variables to be alive. Giving them the scope of that container you will ensure that on the next iteration they are re-created.